# Edit column values based on other column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that I need to update based on values in a couple of columns with values from the columns where needed. NAME is named something else as I know that is bad practice. It is just for the example.

Here is a sample of what I am working with:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def anydigit(text):
    find_digit = re.search(r'\d+', text)
    if find_digit:
        return find_digit.start()
    else:
        return 0

df = pd.DataFrame({'DPID': ['A1', 'A2'], 'NAME': ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'],
                   'ADDR_1': ['123 MAIN ST', 'ATTN: JOHN DOE'], 'ADDR_2': ['', 'P O BOX 123456']})
df['addr_ad1'] = df['ADDR_1'].apply(anydigit)
df['addr_ad2'] = df['ADDR_2'].apply(anydigit)
df['AUX_ADDR_LINE'] = ''
```

This is what needs to happen.

```
If addr_ad1 == 0 and addr_ad2 > 0:
    aux_addr_line = addr_1
    addr_1 = addr_2
    addr_2 = ''
elfif addr_ad1 > 0 and re.sub(r'\s+', '', addr_2)[:4] == 'POBOX':
    aux_addr_line = ''
    addr_1 = addr_1
    addr_2 = ''
elif addr_ad2 > 0 and re.sub(r'\s+', '', addr_1)[:4] == 'POBOX':
    aux_addr_line = ''
    addr_1 = addr_2
    addr_2 = ''
```

I would think that `.apply()` would work, but not sure how I would write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusted some variable names:

```
def anydigit(text):
    find_digit = re.search(r'\d+', text)
    if find_digit:
        return find_digit.start()
    else:
        return 0

df = pd.DataFrame({'DPID': ['A1', 'A2'], 'NAME': ['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'],
                   'addr_1': ['123 MAIN ST', 'ATTN: JOHN DOE'], 'addr_2': ['', 'P O BOX 123456']})
df['addr_ad1'] = df['addr_1'].apply(anydigit)
df['addr_ad2'] = df['addr_2'].apply(anydigit)
df['aux_addr_line'] = ''
```

to start with:

```
  DPID      NAME          addr_1          addr_2  addr_ad1  addr_ad2  \
0   A1  John Doe     123 MAIN ST                         0         0   
1   A2  Jane Doe  ATTN: JOHN DOE  P O BOX 123456         0         8   

  aux_addr_line  
0                
1
```

Defining a function to then `apply` to all rows:

```
def change_address(row):
    if row.addr_ad1 == 0 and row.addr_ad2 > 0:
        row.aux_addr_line = row.addr_1
        row.addr_1 = row.addr_2
        row.addr_2 = ''
    elif row.addr_ad1 > 0 and re.sub(r'\s+', '', row.addr_2)[:4] == 'POBOX':
        row.aux_addr_line = ''
        row.addr_1 = row.addr_1
        row.addr_2 = ''
    elif row.addr_ad2 > 0 and re.sub(r'\s+', '', row.addr_1)[:4] == 'POBOX':
        row.aux_addr_line = ''
        row.addr_1 = row.addr_2
        row.addr_2 = ''
    return row

df = df.apply(change_address, axis=1)
```

to get:

```
  DPID      NAME          addr_1 addr_2  addr_ad1  addr_ad2   aux_addr_line
0   A1  John Doe     123 MAIN ST                0         0                
1   A2  Jane Doe  P O BOX 123456                0         8  ATTN: JOHN DOE
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I removed the addr_ad1 and addr_ad2 columns from the dataframe as they were only needed to make the calculation. I added them to the function like so: addr_ad1 = anydigit(row.addr_1). Thank you!